# Truffle Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545

Tags: web3js, truffle

I am just trying to create a HD  wallet with web3 and truffle to make receive some ethers.  I have installed both of these packages with `npm`. Inside a `node` console, I am trying to run this to get a private/public key :

```
Bip39 = require("bip39");
const mnemonicPhrase = Bip39.generateMnemonic();

const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
Web3 = require('web3');


provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: mnemonicPhrase,
  providerOrUrl: "http://localhost:8545",
  numberOfAddresses: 1,
  shareNonce: true,
  derivationPath: "m/44'/0'/0'/0/"
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
web3.eth.accounts.create()
```

I am running one piece of code after another and just after I run the `provider = new HDWalletProvider()`, I get this error:

```
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:14)
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (C:\Users\Me\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
```

Some people mentioning this error are fixing it with something like `testrpc, geth --rpc` that is apparently used to send the transaction on the ethereum network, but I don't want to do that, I just need to retrieve the private/public key in web3js. I really don't understand what I need to do to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error. I solved it by changing the IP address I had been trying to connect to.

from "https://10.161.162.12:8545" to "http://10.161.162.12:8554"